# format_datetime inside dynamic data type kusto

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I have a function that takes startdate and endDate as inputs. From within the function I perform the below operations-

1. use format_datetime to convert the input date into a specified format
2. use sql_request plugin and pass these formatted dates as sql parameters.

```
let start_time = todynamic(format_datetime(startTs, 'yyyy-MM-dd'));
let end_time = todynamic(format_datetime(endTs, 'yyyy-MM-dd'));
let query = 'select * from [db].[Table] where date > @param0 and date < @param1';
let result = evaluate sql_request(auth, query, dynamic({'param0': start_time, 'param1': end_time}))
```

However, on the editor I get syntax error on start_time as it says "expected '}' " and also on sql_request saying that sql_request expects 4 arguments.

How do I pass formatted datetime as part of dynamic data type? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, at this point plugins support only constant arguments.
This might change in the future.

Some additional remarks:

- Parameters names must start with `@` (both in the SQL query and the SQL parameters definition)
- Parameters might have a datetime type. No need to convert them to string type.
- `dynamic()` can only be used with constants, E.g. `dynamic({"x":1,"y":2})`.

  For non constants we should use [pack(), bag_pack()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/packfunction) or [pack_dictionary()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/packdictionaryfunction) (all aliases to each other), E.g.

  ```
  let x_val = 1;  
  let y_val = 2;  
  let my_dict = pack_dictionary("x", x_val, "y", y_val);
  print my_dict
  ```

  | print_0 |
  | --- |
  | {"x":1,"y":2} |

###### Demo:

```
let connection_string   = h'Server=tcp:dumarkov.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=mydb;Encrypt=True;Authentication="Active Directory Integrated";';
let sql_query           = "select * from sys.tables where create_date >= @mydatetime";
let sql_parameters      = dynamic({"@mydatetime":datetime("2022-06-21 00:00:00")});
evaluate sql_request(connection_string, sql_query, sql_parameters)
```

| name | object_id | principal_id | schema_id | parent_object_id | type | type_desc | create_date | modify_date | is_ms_shipped | is_published | is_schema_published | lob_data_space_id | filestream_data_space_id | max_column_id_used | lock_on_bulk_load | uses_ansi_nulls | is_replicated | has_replication_filter | is_merge_published | is_sync_tran_subscribed | has_unchecked_assembly_data | text_in_row_limit | large_value_types_out_of_row | is_tracked_by_cdc | lock_escalation | lock_escalation_desc | is_filetable | is_memory_optimized | durability | durability_desc | temporal_type | temporal_type_desc | history_table_id | is_remote_data_archive_enabled | is_external | history_retention_period | history_retention_period_unit | history_retention_period_unit_desc | is_node | is_edge | data_retention_period | data_retention_period_unit | data_retention_period_unit_desc | ledger_type | ledger_type_desc | ledger_view_id | is_dropped_ledger_table |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| hello | 1605580758 |  | 1 | 0 | U | USER_TABLE | 2022-06-23T14:22:23.723Z | 2022-06-23T14:22:23.723Z | false | false | false | 0 |  | 1 | false | true | false | false | false | false | false | 0 | false | false | 0 | TABLE | false | false | 0 | SCHEMA_AND_DATA | 0 | NON_TEMPORAL_TABLE |  | false | false |  |  |  | false | false | -1 | -1 | INFINITE | 0 | NON_LEDGER_TABLE |  | false |
| world | 1653580929 |  | 1 | 0 | U | USER_TABLE | 2022-06-25T09:21:28.36Z | 2022-06-25T09:21:28.36Z | false | false | false | 0 |  | 1 | false | true | false | false | false | false | false | 0 | false | false | 0 | TABLE | false | false | 0 | SCHEMA_AND_DATA | 0 | NON_TEMPORAL_TABLE |  | false | false |  |  |  | false | false | -1 | -1 | INFINITE | 0 | NON_LEDGER_TABLE |  | false |